SharePoint User Profiles service account
I want to create a new service account that is only permitted to edit all user profiles - specifically anyone's manager field and their photo.
Can you advise how I might grant those and only those permissions? It's ok if they can edit any of the user profile fields if that's easier.
Thanks,
